# Put pages in folder

Tags: windows-phone-7

I put all of my application pages into a folder "Pages" and my application broke down. It hits both of the following lines in App.xaml.cs and except this it doesn't print any errors.

```
private void RootFrame_NavigationFailed(object sender, NavigationFailedEventArgs e)

...
private void Application_UnhandledException(object sender, applicationUnhandledExceptionEventArgs e)
```

How can I fix it?

Comment: What is the Uri it is trying to navigate to?

Comment: @ananthonline It happens just after applications starts. So probably the root page url isn't updated, but I don't know where to look for it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your WMAppManifest.xml you'll find the following:

```
    <Tasks>
      <DefaultTask Name="_default" NavigationPage="MainPage.xaml" />
    </Tasks>
```

Change the NavigationPage value to "/Pages/MainPage.xaml" and everything should work good.

Hope this helps!